# preserve my env in linux screen

Tags: linux, bash, screenrc

I have serveral customized environment variables and functions in my ~/.bash_profile which I would like to be called automatically when I start my screen session with `screen -D -R`, but apparently adding `source ~/.bash_profile` in `~/.screenrc` doesn't solve my issue.

On every new screen I have to manually source the bash_profile.

I have noticed that this file can't be found while creating a new screen (when you create new screen there is the the line in the bottom showing what commands are executing and it returns that the file can't be found.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is only run by login shells.

`~/.bashrc` is run by other interactive shells, such as those started by `screen`.

`~/.screenrc` is a screen configuration file, and is not used to configure bash.

Put things that should be set up per shell in `~/.bashrc`, and add `source ~/.bashrc` to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: still the same issue, when opening a new screen I am receiving this thing: `.screenrc : source ~/.bashrc: No Such file or directory`

Comment: @Amir You seem to have modified `.screenrc` instead of `.bash_profile` as suggested here

Comment: I did change the `~/.bashrc` as well, but just put that source so that it def runs it.

Comment: @Amir It doesn't do what you think it does. You should remove it. To see that this works, put `export MYTEST=foo` in your `.bashrc`, open a new screen window, and run `echo $MYTEST`. Make very sure not to confuse the three files. Do not add the export line to `.screenrc` or to `.bash_profile`, only `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try configuring `screen` to run a login-shell by default.

Screen runs a sub-shell, unless told otherwise (See "shell" .screenrc command). Example `.screenrc` entry to run a login-shell:

```
shell -$SHELL
```